# What do you call the servants who follow a king during a procession?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the servants who follow a king during a procession? I am pretty sure there was a word for it, but I don't know if the word only applied to the people in a procession or not.

Comment: Attendants? But servants wouldn’t normally be in a royal procession; that was reserved for other nobles (including the king’s family) and sometimes clerics, in order of rank.

Comment: Entourage - a group of people surrounding an important person.

Comment: I assume you mean 'officials in the King's service' rather than 'domestic servants'. Ram's suggestion is a good one; you could use 'courtiers' in a historical context. It might depend on what kind of procession it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One term is **retinue** for which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/retinue) has

> **retinue**
>
> NOUN
> A group of advisers, assistants, or others accompanying an important person.
>
> *The scale and precise role of the retinue of officers and servants who travelled with a prince has not been established.*

Comment: This word is not exclusive to a *procession* or to a *king*. Can you clarify the question, please.